# JavaScript: show password on hold

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have 2 inputs for passwords. Each input field has 'show' button, which shows password on holding that button.

```
<form name="resetting_form" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" id="password_first" required="required" placeholder="New Password" class="form-control">
        <span class="show">show</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" id="password_second" required="required" placeholder="Repeat Password" class="form-control">
        <span class="show">show</span>
    </div>  
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is what I have

```
$(".form-control").on("keyup",function(){
    if ($(this).val())
        $(".show").show();
    else
        $(".show").hide();
});

$(".show").mousedown(function(){
    $(".form-control").attr('type','text');
}).mouseup(function(){
    $(".form-control").attr('type','password');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(".form-control").attr('type','password');
});
```

Problem

When I click to 'show' button, both input fields are shown. How to make sure that only corresponding password is shown?

Comment: The bottom solutions look good, however I wouldn't bind it against a bootstrap class. You're risking leaking out many eventListeners. A possible optimization would be to bind under a parent reference: $('.form-control', '#some-parent-id').//logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `$(".form-control")`, jquery select all `.form-control` element. But you need to select target element using `this` variable in event function and use [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to select previous element.

```js
$(".show").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).prev().attr('type','text');
}).mouseup(function(){
    $(this).prev().attr('type','password');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).prev().attr('type','password');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just target the previous input instead of all inputs with the given class

```js
 $(".form-control").on("keyup", function() {
   if ($(this).val())
     $(this).next(".show").show();
   else
     $(this).next(".show").hide();
 }).trigger('keyup');

 $(".show").mousedown(function() {
   $(this).prev(".form-control").prop('type', 'text');
 }).mouseup(function() {
   $(this).prev(".form-control").prop('type', 'password');
 }).mouseout(function() {
   $(this).prev(".form-control").prop('type', 'password');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="resetting_form" method="post" action="">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="password" id="password_first" required="required" placeholder="New Password" class="form-control">
    <span class="show">show</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="password" id="password_second" required="required" placeholder="Repeat Password" class="form-control">
    <span class="show">show</span>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

**In react We simply do with**

---

We probably need to use the onMouseDown and onMouseUp, onMouseOut events

```
onMouseDown={handleShowPassword}
onMouseUp={handleShowPassword}
onMouseOut={handleShowPasswordHideOnMouseOut}
```

Comment: Look at the tags on the question (and the code in it). They're using jQuery, not React.

Comment: You also failed to defined any of the functions you are passing to the event handler props.